# How to get list of touched files between 2 points of time?

Tags: linux, files, monitoring

I need to get a full list of files modified, and if possible files accessed too, by a complex script, as well as all files accessed at the same time of the script running by any other process.

So i want to START logging all IO file access before the application start, and then STOP logging when it ends. (or inspect full log between 2 time stamps ?)

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a marker file, touching it before you perform the operation of your main concern, and then using the `find` command with the `-newer` or `-anewer` options to find files that were modified or access after you touched the marker file.

```
touch /tmp/marker
perform-some-operation
find /path/to/dir -newer /tmp/marker
```

If the directory you want to monitor is not too large,
an interesting alternative could be to convert it to a Git repository,
and then use Git commands to see what has changed.

```
cd /path/to/dir
git init .
git add .
git commit -m init
perform-some-operation
git status
git diff
```

After you are done, you can simply delete the `.git` directory.